# transport error from firebase admin when try to validate jwt

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

the final line in this Python code:

```
    from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app
    from firebase_admin import auth as firebaseAuth
    _cred = credentials.Certificate('common/auth/touchstone-firebase-adminsdk-4a750c3d1c53.json')
    tsFirebaseApp = initialize_app(_cred)
    decoded_token_dict = firebaseAuth.verify_id_token(id_token, tsFirebaseApp)
```

is throwing this stack trace & I can't find anything explaining it....

```
ERROR    2017-07-30 20:10:15,986 service.py:191] Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: TransportError (('Connection aborted.', error(22, 'Invalid argument')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1331, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 414, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/ferris3/endpoints.py", line 232, in inner
    return_val = func(self, request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/service_backend/user_service.py", line 80, in createOrLoadUser
    user, appSettings, err = processUserSignupOrSignin(access_token, request.idpProfileAtts)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/common/auth/login.py", line 38, in processUserSignupOrSignin
    firUserAsDict, err = userFromJwTokenIfValid(access_token)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/common/auth/login.py", line 60, in userFromJwTokenIfValid
    decoded_token_dict = firebaseAuth.verify_id_token(id_token)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/firebase_admin/auth.py", line 98, in verify_id_token
    return token_generator.verify_id_token(id_token)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/firebase_admin/auth.py", line 277, in verify_id_token
    audience=project_id)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 115, in verify_firebase_token
    id_token, request, audience=audience, certs_url=_GOOGLE_APIS_CERTS_URL)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 76, in verify_token
    certs = _fetch_certs(request, certs_url)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 50, in _fetch_certs
    response = request(certs_url, method='GET')
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 115, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(exc)
TransportError: ('Connection aborted.', error(22, 'Invalid argument'))
INFO     2017-07-30 20:10:15,999 module.py:832] default: "POST /_ah/spi/UserService.createOrLoadUser HTTP/1.1" 500 512
INFO     2017-07-30 20:10:15,999 module.py:832] default: "POST /_ah/api/tstone/v1/user/createOrLoadUser?prettyPrint=false HTTP/1.1" 503 196
```

I've properly created a service key, downloaded and imported the associated .json config file, and initialized the tsFirebaseApp with the credentials.
I'm not sure what else to try?